# Introduce a concept versus give an introduction to the concept

Tags: word-usage

Looking for a shorter way to write *In this chapter, I give an introduction to concept A* in an academic text, I realized a subtle difference in (academic) English:

- *I introduce concept A*: I am creating/suggesting a new concept A
- *I give an introduction to concept A*: I am explaining in gentle terms the already existing concept A.

Is this distinction correct? If so, what would be a shorter way to express *I give an introduction to*? I summarise? (but a summary is not exactly an introduction...). Maybe I could say, *I introduce the reader to concept A*, or *this chapter introduce concept A*?

Thanks!